# How to allow user to input the subnet mask for IPv6 address? Is it really necessary?

Tags: networking, web, ipv6

the application I am developing needs to support both IPv4 and IPv6 page. The application exposes a web page for user to configure the server details as follows. This is perfect for IPv4 address.

As the IPv6 address embeds the subnet within the IP Address itself, it's a bit confusing how to accept the subnet information.

[image: Input form]

I can take the following approaches

- User has an IPv6 address which contains information including subnet mask. Let the user enters the whole stuffs on screen and we will disable IPv4 subnet mask text box.
- User has an IPv6 address without the subnet information. we will allow user to enter the subnet information in the subnet textbox and later merge the information together to prepare the full IPv6 address.

The second method methods seems not elegant. In my understanding, simply taking `ipconfig` from the console, the `IPv6` address it displays contains the subnet information as well. So that user can easily enter this information in the input page. What's the standard way of doing this?

Comment: Subnet mask is two words `:P`

Comment: The subnet mask is often used to calculate the broadcast address, IPv6 has no concept of IP broadcast and applications must now use IP multicast instead.  It may indeed be redundant for the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix length (subnet mask) is never part of the address. Just like you can write address+prefixlen as 192.0.2.0/24 in IPv4 you write 2001:db8:0:2::/64 in IPv6. Much easier than the old 255.255.255.0 subnet mask notation.

I would use the more convenient (CIDR) notation for both IPv4 and IPv6, and in one textbox. Much easier when copy&pasteing :-)

Comment: IPv4 has both subnet mask and effective prefix length, IPv6 only has prefix length.

Comment: Unless you use weird non-contiguous subnet masks they are exactly the same. If you are thinking about classful adressing: please forget it. That has been replaced by CIDR in 1993...

Comment: It's legacy from a users viewpoint but all the APIs and ABIs expect a subnet mask in IPv4 and a prefix in IPv6.  It would be nice to see IPv4 APIs take a prefix but none do.

Comment: I see plenty applications that accept CIDR notation for IPv4 in input, config files etc. And if an API or ABI wants it in the legacy format then it's easy to convert.